# In PostgreSQL, how can I use each element in an array as a key in another table?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

There is a SQL query as follows:

Query A:

```sql
SELECT
    user,
    color_id_array
FROM
    relation;
```

Result A:

```
user, color_id_array
john, [1, 2]
bob, [2, 2, 2]
amy, [2, 2, 3]
```

Query B:

```sql
SELECT
    inf_name,
    inf_code
FROM
    infomation;
```

Result B:

```
inf_code, inf_name
1, red
2, green
3, blue
```

The color_id_array in Result A is an array that allows duplicate elements. How can you create a query to obtain the following output? The DB being used is PostgreSQL.

Desired output:

```
user, color_id_array, color_name_array
john, [1, 2], ["red", "green"]
bob, [2, 2, 2], ["green", "green", "green"]
amy, [2, 2, 3], ["green", "green", "blue"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unnest the array of ids (while keeping track of their original position), bring the information table with a join, then aggregate again:

```
select r.*, array_agg(i.inf_name order by rx.color_seq) color_name_array
from relation r
cross join lateral unnest(r.color_id_array) with ordinality rx(color_code, color_seq)
inner join information i on i.inf_code = rx.color_code
group by r.user
```

The `group by` clause should contain the primary key of the `relation` table (I assumed `user`).

| usr | color_id_array | color_name_array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| amy | {2,2,3} | {green,green,blue} |
| bob | {2,2,2} | {green,green,green} |
| john | {1,2} | {red,green} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qdDUmymA)